# Returning a new array using pointers

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that returns an array with the indexes of another array as elements when that array's element =1.

So if array[ix]=1 then newarray[newarrcounter]=ix.

However the array that is returned only has 0s as elements.

I'm trying to do this using only pointers and no indexing. Am I using pointers incorrectly here?

```
int* primearr(int arr[], int size, int& newarrsize){
    int* end = arr + size;
    int* begin = arr;
      while(begin<end){
        if(*begin==1)
          ++newarrsize;
        begin++;
      }
      begin=arr;

    int *newarray= new int[newarrsize];
      while(begin<end){
        if(*begin==1){
          *newarray=begin-arr;
          newarray++;
        }
        begin++;
      }
    return newarray;
}
```

the rest of the  program code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int* arr(int size);
int firstprime(int size, int arr[]);
void crossout(int size, int*arr, int factor);
void findzeros(int arr[], int size);
int* primearr(int arr[], int size,int& newarrsize);


int main()
{
    int low, high;
    char again='y';
    high=low=0;
    int firstn;
    int newarrsize=0;

    cout<<"\tThe Sieve of Eratosthenes"<<endl<<endl;
    do{
    do{
     do{
        cout<<"Enter the high boundary: ";
        cin>>high;
        cout<<endl;
        if(high<=0)
        cout<<"ERROR: HIGH BOUNDARY MUST BE POSITIVE"<<endl;
      }while(high<0);

      do{
        cout<<"Enter the low boundary: ";
        cin>>low;
        cout<<endl;
        if(low<=0)
        cout<<"ERROR: LOW BOUNDARY MUST BE POSITIVE"<<endl;
        }while(low<=0);
     if(low>high)
                cout<<"ERROR: HIGH BOUNDARY MUST BE GREATER THAN LOW BOUNDARY"<<endl;
    }while(low>=high);

    int* thearr= arr(high);

    firstn=firstprime(high,thearr);

    do{
      crossout(high,thearr,firstn);
      firstn=firstprime(high,thearr);
    }while(firstn<= sqrt(high));

    findzeros(thearr,high);

    int* thenewarr= primearr(thearr,high,newarrsize);

    cout<<"The prime numbers from "<<low<<" to "<<high<<" are: "<<endl;
    int* begin = thenewarr;
    int* end = thenewarr+newarrsize;
    while(begin<=end){
      cout<<*thenewarr<<"  ";
      ++begin;
    }

    cout<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Try again with new boundaries? (y/n):"<<endl;
    cin>>again;

    delete[] thearr;
    delete[] thenewarr; 

    }while(again=='y');

   return 0;
}

int* arr(int size){
    int* thearray = new int[size]();
    thearray[0] = -1;
    thearray[1] = -1;
    return thearray;
}

int firstprime(int size, int arr[]){
  int* end = arr + size;
  int* begin = arr;
    while(begin<end){
        if(*begin==0)
            return (begin-arr);
        begin++;
    }
    return -1;
}

void crossout(int size, int*arr, int factor){
    int* end = arr + size;
    int* begin = arr;
    int newfactor=factor+factor;
    while(begin<end){
        if((begin-arr)==factor)
          *begin=1;
        else if((begin-arr)==newfactor){
          *begin=-1;
          newfactor=newfactor+factor;
        }
        begin++;
    }
}

void findzeros(int arr[], int size){
    int* end = arr + size;
    int* begin = arr;
    while(begin<=end){
        if(*begin==0)
            *begin=1;
        begin++;
    }
}

int* primearr(int arr[], int size, int& newarrsize){
    int* end = arr + size;
    int* begin = arr;
      while(begin<end){
        if(*begin==1)
          ++newarrsize;
        begin++;
      }
      begin=arr;

    int *newarray= new int[newarrsize];
      while(begin<end){
        if(*begin==1){
          *newarray=begin-arr;
          newarray++;
        }
        begin++;
      }
    return newarray;
}
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use `std::vector`.  This type of C++ coding has gone out with the dark ages.

Comment: My professor had been teaching for 20 years and insists we go about it this way.

Comment: Well no wonder students dump C++ and go right to Java or JavaScript after finishing C++ if C++ is being taught this way.  Your professor is probably a `C` programmer teaching C++, and simply doing what they were taught in `C`.

Comment: I've been teaching on and off for far  longer than that, and I insist you don't.

Comment: And also, you are not using pointers correctly.   You're making a lot of mistakes.

Comment: Even though its ancient, I would still appreciate an explanation to what I'm doing wrong so I can atleast understand it.

Comment: @TaylorLoslo You should post *how* you're using this function, not just this function.  I bet that the usage of such code is also wrought with errors (such as memory leaks).  That's the deal you make if you insist on using pointers -- the code that uses such function better be correct also.

Comment: To be honest I can't really understand your criteria for selecting elements for the new array, can you clarify?

Comment: I seriously hope no one is down-voting this question because they don't like the teacher's methods.

Comment: Learning what's wrong is reasonable. My request is that you run your program in up the debugging tool that came with your development environment, place a breakpoint in the function, run the  program, and then step through the function.  Do this before asking questions and you probably won't have to ask the question. The debugger is the programmer's secret weapon and being able to watch what your programs are doing as they do it is both educational and will save you a bucket load of time.

Comment: @TaylorLoslo `newarrsize` is not initialized, yet your first loop increments it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie not in the function at any rate. It could be set correctly before being passed in though.

Comment: The elements of the old array are all equal -1 or 1. If the index of the old array is a prime number then it equals one, otherwise -1. The new array is just a list of the prime numbers. So arr[2]=1 then I want newarr[counter]=2.

Comment: Although I agree with @PaulMcKenzie to use std::vector in this case, there is nothing wrong with using pointers or allocating memory with new[] in C++. It's a good skill and you should learn it. I've been doing it for decades too. Just be careful and don't let co-workers who don't know what they're doing modify your code. new[] has its use. Especially when you are squeezing performance out of image processing. What disturbs me about C++ is the way modern C++ being is written -- it's so far removed from C++ of even 15 years ago it's almost completely unrecognizable.

Comment: @user4581301 -- Which is why posting *how* the function is used would be beneficial.  But even so, the function's purpose at the beginning is to size up the number of entries, thus `newarrsize` should be initialized in that function.

Comment: Here's another vital point that never seems to be taught in school: start with something small and simple that works, then build up. In this case you could try writing a function that creates and returns a small array of a fixed size, say [1,1,1]. A bug like the one in your code would have prevented this, and been *much* easier to find in such a simple function.

Comment: @TaylorLoslo `int* thenewarr= primearr(thearr,high,newarrsize);` -- Well, I may be correct.  A bug since `newarrsize` is not reset.  As was pointed out already -- you should have just written that function, and write maybe a 4 or 5 line `main` function to just test the function you have.  Instead you wrote a function that, unless everything on the outside is working correctly, will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing `newarrsize` to 0 before calculating the new array's size.

After allocating the new array, when you are then populating it, you are incrementing the pointer to the new array.  So, when the function exits, you are not returning a pointer to the front of the new array, you are returning a pointer that is past the end of the new array.  Not only does this prevent the caller from accessing the indexes you want, but it also prevents the caller from being able to `delete[]` the array correctly when done using it.

Try this instead:

```
int* primearr(int arr[], int size, int& newarrsize) {
    int* begin = arr;
    int* end = begin + size;

    newarrsize = 0;
    while (begin < end) {
        if (*begin == 1)
            ++newarrsize;
        ++begin;
    }

    int *newarray = new int[newarrsize];

    int *ptr = newarray;
    begin = arr;
    while (begin < end) {
        if (*begin == 1) {
            *ptr = begin - arr;
            ++ptr;
        }
        ++begin;
    }

    return newarray;
}
```

That being said, you really should be using `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<int> primearr(int arr[], int size) {
    int* begin = arr;
    int* end = begin + size;

    std::vector<int> ret;

    while (begin < end) {
        if (*begin == 1)
            ret.push_back(begin - arr);
        ++begin;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

If not, at least use `std::unique_ptr` so you can maintain ownership of the array at all times, and the caller doesn't have to worry about deallocating the array manually:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> primearr(int arr[], int size, int& newarrsize) {
    int* begin = arr;
    int* end = begin + size;

    newarrsize = 0;
    while (begin < end) {
        if (*begin == 1)
            ++newarrsize;
        ++begin;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<int[]> newarray(new int[newarrsize]);
    // or, in C++14 and later:
    // auto newarray = std::make_unique<int[]>(newarrsize);

    int *ptr = newarray.get();
    begin = arr;
    while (begin < end) {
        if (*begin == 1) {
            *ptr = begin - arr;
            ++ptr;
        }
        ++begin;
    }

    return std::move(newarray);
}
```

Comment: I had to change the last loop to while(begin<=end) so the last element of the  new array doesn't = 0, but otherwise thank you so much.

Comment: `begin < end` is correct. `end` does not point at a valid element of `arr` but at 1 past the last element (intentional and correct). Dereferencing `begin` when `begin == end` would be *undefined behavior* and likely to crash. Besides, it shouldn't matter if the last element of `newarray` is 0 or not (unless you have logic errors outside of this function). The only way the last element of `newarray` could be 0 is if the input `size` is 1 and the 1st element of `arr` is 1. The caller is expected to use `newarraysize` to know how many elements are in the `newarray` regardless of their values.